# Can I optimise my React App reconciliation for performance?

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools, reconciliation

I am optimising the performance of my React app. Most state changes seem to result in the following "Timings" in the chrome devtools performance tab:

[image: "Timings" in the chrome devtools performance tab]

As you can see, a fair chunk of time is spent on the reconciliation (completed root) step. This always seems to start at the root of the application (BrowserRouter)

[image: BrowserRouter [update]]

Is this the expected behaviour or should I ideally be seeing only a subtree of the component in which state is changing being reconciliated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After further research, its seems that reconciliation may always start from the root and thus the main performance improvement that could be made is to simplify the component tree

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use the Rendering-Paint flashing to checkout which componets have changed

[image]